why SGL give me djanfo.db.utils.integrityError ?idk what that means

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'flights_flight' with
primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: flights_flight.origin_id
contains a value 'New York' that does not have a corresponding value
in flights_airport.id.

When I run python manage.py migrate this appears.
This is the code:
def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'airline.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I tried to write another value for New York but it doesn't work either


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

The error message says it all. You tried to insert a flight from a non-existing airport.

It seems the origin_id column in the flights_flight table references the primary key of the flights_airport table. The value 'New York' in flights_flight.origin_id does not correspond to any valid id in the flights_airport table.
So, ensure your foreign key relationship code in your modles.py, or check your data in your flights_flight table, maybe delete the row where flights_flight.origin_id = 'New York'
